How to tweak app icon size in the app "drawer" Ubuntu 24.04?
I have searched far and wide on how to change the size of icons in the app drawer, no good results yet. How can we change it? Are there any extensions for this purpose?
(Please don't confuse the dock icons with app drawer's icons)

I just found an extension for this purpose. V-Shell (optional vertical workspaces), awesome amount of tweaks.
see the resized icons, even allows empty space
